# How to make MxN piechart plots with one legend and removed y-axis titles in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

f, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    df[col].plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.2f', ax=ax, title=col, fontsize=10)
    ax.legend(loc=3)
    plt.ylabel("")
    plt.xlabel("")

plt.show()
```

Which makes the following plot:

[image]

How can I make the following:

- M=2 x N=2 plot, the values of M and N can change.
- Remove the y-title axis
- Remove legends
- Save it to a file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Multiple Pie Charts with a Shared Legend

In my opinion, it's easier to plot things manually with `matplotlib` than to use a `pandas` dataframe plotting method, in this case.  That way you have more control.  You can add a legend to only the first axes after plotting all of your pie charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    ax.pie(df[col], labels=df.index, autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')

axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))

fig.savefig('your_file.png') # Or whichever format you'd like
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Use `pandas` Plotting Methods Instead

However, if you'd prefer to use the plotting method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    df[col].plot(kind='pie', legend=False, ax=ax, autopct='%0.2f', title=col,
                 colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', aspect='equal')

axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))

fig.savefig('your_file.png')
plt.show()
```

Both produce identical results.

---

## Rearranging Subplot Grid

If you'd like to have a 2x2 or other grid arrangement of plots, `plt.subplots` will return a 2D array of axes.  Therefore, you'd need to iterate over `axes.flat` instead of `axes` directly.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax, col in zip(axes.flat, df.columns):
    ax.pie(df[col], labels=df.index, autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')

axes[0, 0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))

fig.savefig('your_file.png') # Or whichever format you'd like
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Other Grid Arrangements

If you'd like a grid arrangement that has more axes than the amount of data you have, you'll need to hide any axes that you don't plot on.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.axis('off')

for ax, col in zip(axes.flat, df.columns):
    ax.pie(df[col], labels=df.index, autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')

axes[0, 0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))

fig.savefig('your_file.png') # Or whichever format you'd like
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Omitting Labels

If you don't want the labels around the outside, omit the `labels` argument to `pie`.  However, when we do this, we'll need to build up the legend manually by passing in artists and labels for the artists.  This is also a good time to demonstrate using `fig.legend` to align the single legend relative to the figure.  We'll place the legend in the center, in this case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax, col in zip(axes.flat, df.columns):
    artists = ax.pie(df[col], autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')

fig.legend(artists[0], df.index, loc='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Moving Percentage Labels Outside

Similarly, the radial position of the percentage labels is controlled by the `pctdistance` kwarg.  Values greater than 1 will move the percentage labels outside the pie.  However, the default text alignment for the percentage labels (centered) assumes they're inside the pie.  Once they're moved outside the pie, we'll need to use a different alignment convention.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)
import pandas as pd

def align_labels(labels):
    for text in labels:
        x, y = text.get_position()
        h_align = 'left' if x > 0 else 'right'
        v_align = 'bottom' if y > 0 else 'top'
        text.set(ha=h_align, va=v_align)

df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  columns=['x', 'y','z','w'])

plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax, col in zip(axes.flat, df.columns):
    artists = ax.pie(df[col], autopct='%.2f', pctdistance=1.05, colors=colors)
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')
    align_labels(artists[-1])

fig.legend(artists[0], df.index, loc='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I also like to control the plot matrix, e,g,   M=2xN=2 plot or 3x1 plot.

Comment: I tried modifying to `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,5))` but won't work.

Comment: @neversaint - In that case, you'd want to iterate over `axes.flat`, as `axes` will be a 2D array.

Comment: You mean your 2nd example? I tried but the legend is gone. Can you give example?

Comment: Thanks a million. Lastly, is there a way to remove the label 'abcd' around the pie, but keeping the 1 legend? I tried `label=None`, but won't do.  Also how can I push the percentage value the outside of the pie.

Comment: Would you mind seeing the related post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035427/conditional-removal-of-labels-in-matplotlib-pie-chart

Comment: @neversaint - I've updated the answer to show examples of both of those.  Sorry for the delay. Work got in the way :)