# Showing one label on pie chart pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graph, label, pie-chart

Is there a way of showing just one set of label? At the moment it is looking very messy and I would like to have one set of label please. I did `label=None` and it turned off all the labels. [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a bit change [How to make MxN piechart plots with one legend and removed y-axis titles in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034457/how-to-make-mxn-piechart-plots-with-one-legend-and-removed-y-axis-titles-in-matp):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'beer':[1,2,3],
                   'spirit':[4,5,6],
                   'wine':[7,8,9]}, index=['Africa','Asia','Europe'])

print (df)
        beer  spirit  wine
Africa     1       4     7
Asia       2       5     8
Europe     3       6     9

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10,3))
for ax, idx in zip(axes, df.index):
    ax.pie(df.loc[idx], labels=df.columns, autopct='%.2f')
    ax.set(ylabel='', title=idx, aspect='equal')

axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]