# Common legend for multiple pie chart plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pie-chart

How do i set a commond legend for both chart at the bottom of the chart. I tried using fig.legend but do not know how to write it correctly. Thanks!!

```
import pandas as pd

# Intialise data to Dicts of series.
d = {'Oil' : pd.Series([1.0, 17.0, 0.3, 81.7],
                       index =['Others', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Domestic']),
        'Coal' : pd.Series([3, 34.8,  38.6, 23.6],
                        index =['Others', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Domestic'])}
  
# creates Dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(15,4.5))

fig.suptitle('Customers Profile and Energy Sold per Sector', fontweight='bold', fontsize=20)
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    ax.pie(df[col], wedgeprops=dict(linewidth = 3, edgecolor = 'white'), colors=['#EE8434','#C95D63', '#AE8799','#717EC3'],startangle=90, autopct='%.2f%%', pctdistance=1.2)
     
#fig.legend(ax, df.index, 'upper left')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make MxN piechart plots with one legend and removed y-axis titles in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034457/how-to-make-mxn-piechart-plots-with-one-legend-and-removed-y-axis-titles-in-matp)

Comment: @HenryEcker it did help!!! Thanks a many i used another code instead

`for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    chart = ax.pie(df[col]     
fig.legend(chart[0], df.index, 'lower center')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found in link suggested by @henryecker

```
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    chart = ax.pie(df[col])
     
fig.legend(chart[0], df.index, 'lower center')
```